# How to capture to system default album using Camera class

Tags: android

I just complete my photo app to using "Camera" class related implement.
However I could not see my capture photo in default Android photo album app.
Here is my code segment from my callback from Camera.takePicture:

```
    PictureCallback jpegPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);

        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString()
                + File.separator
                + "DCIM" 
                + File.separator 
                + "Camera"
                + File.separator
                + "PicTest_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
            file.getParentFile().mkdir();
        }

        try {
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(file));
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bos);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            Toast.makeText(MainPage.this, "Picture work " + fileName + "!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainPage.this, "Picture Failed" + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
};
```

Please provide any idea for this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MediaScannerConnection` to tell the `MediaStore` to index your photo.

Also, please use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`, rather than the hardcoded subdirectory that you are using.

Also also, rather than decoding the `byte[]` to a `Bitmap`, then re-encoding it as a `byte[]`, you might consider just saving the `byte[]`.

Also also also, `onPictureTaken()` is called on the main application thread AFAIK; please do your image manipulations and saving to disk in a background thread.

Comment: Thank you, it totally work. I am looking for this answer for long time.